# Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

Im having error on the Facebook Javascript "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null " line 187 and line 187 is:

`" button.onclick = function() {"`

All the code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({ appId: <?php echo json_encode($this->getApiKey()) ?>, 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});
 FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height:1500 });
 //FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
 function updateButton(response) {
    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

    if (response.authResponse == 'null') {
      //user is already logged in and connected
      var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {


      });

      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          userInfo.innerHTML="";
    });
      };
    } else {
      //user is not connected to your app or logged out
      //button.innerHTML = 'Login';
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
if(response.status=='connected') setLocation('<?php echo $this->getConnectUrl() ?>');
      if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');


        });  

          } else {
            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
          }
         }, {scope:'email, user_birthday'});    
      }
    }
  }

  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
  //FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);  
};

(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol 
    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

</script>
```

If need more information just tell me
I appreciate the help.
Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at your code suggest that the button does not exist when you try to access it:

```
function updateButton(response) {
    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');
    //there is no element with id fb-auth
    console.log("button is now:",button);
```

Please put some console.log in there like the example above after you've set the button variable and before trying to use it and then update your question where exactly it goes wrong.

Use Chrome or Firefox with firebug plugin to see proper console.logs and press F12 to open the dev tools (opens console tab by default).

[UPDATE]

I've removed the code referring to the fb-auth button so if that code was old and unused then the following should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({ appId: <?php echo json_encode($this->getApiKey()) ?>, 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});
 FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height:1500 });
 function updateButton(response) {
    if (response.authResponse == 'null') {
     //user is already logged in and connected
     var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
     });
    } else {
  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
  //FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);  
};

(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol 
    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

Comment: It says `button is now: null ` .

Comment: Are you calling updateButton function too soon? It seems there is no element with the id "fb-auth" so you can't add an onclick event to it. Your code doesn't show when fbAsyncInit is called but my guess it's called when content isn't loaded yet or you're expecting content that isn't there.

Comment: Right, there is no calling to fb-auth i just changed the call to..
<a href="#" title="Facebook Connect" rel="facebook-connect" id="fb-auth"><img style="width:65px;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flogin.jpg') ?>" id="facebook" alt="facebook login" /></a>
But still the same.. That call is a html that is not showing on the web, i mean noone will go there..

Comment: The html code you posted; is that part of your page? If it is then document.getElementById("fb-auth") should not return null unless your code and the href are in different frames.

Comment: Yes its part of my page, but like i say that web never is used is the old login. How i can fix that?. The code off the error is on prototype.js and the code "<a href="#" title="Facebook Connect" rel="facebook-connect" id="fb-auth">..." are in the old Login.

Comment: If i put that code to any web and go there the Error dissapear, but if i change the webpage which dont call that id it give the error again. How to make to dont call every moment that code?, on every web? or how to make dissapear that error without putting the code on all the webs.

Comment: "The code off the error is on prototype.js" So you have a different error now? var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info'); is from your code right; not from prototype?

Comment: No, i make a mistake explaining, the error still the same but like you say the " is called but my guess it's called when content isn't loaded yet" , if the button is loaded "<a href="#" title="Facebook Connect" rel="facebook-connect" id="fb-auth"><img style="width:65px;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flogin.jpg') ?>" id="facebook" alt="facebook login" /></a>" the error dissapear, so How to fix it without putting the button on the webpage?

Comment: @MarkAnthon I see, I've updated the answer and removed the code that referred to the old code that isn't used anymore. You can try and see if that works.

Comment: Is giving this error : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">

Comment: @MarkAnthon Do you know how to use the developer tools in the browser? Can you open it with Chrome and press F12 then check out the console to see WHERE the error comes from? What line and if it's caused by Javascript at all?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because your JavaScript is not at the bottom of your page and when it runs, the DOM tree is not built yet. try placing your code in a different part of your html page, after your elements are built.